# can't fetch local json file in electron-vue

Tags: json, vue.js, electron, axios

I try to fetch a local json file in my project.
Tried the following:

```js
import axios from 'axios';
import userDataJson from './../data/userData.json';

export const userDataControllerMixin = {
  data() {
    return {
      users: [],
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.getUsers();
  },
  methods: {
    getUsers() {
      // TODO: load userObj.json initial to prevent reset the userData.json all the time
      fetch(userDataJson)
        .then((response) => {
          console.log(response);
        }).catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
        });
    };
```

i also tried it with axios before but they all lead into this error msg:

```js
GET http://localhost:9080/[object%20Object] 404 (Not Found)
```

What am i doing wrong? Looks like a config issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont need to call fetch method anymore since you are importing your json data from the file. What you can do is, since you are already importing the json data, then when the component is mounted just assign the json data to the user array:

```
data() {
    return {
      users: [],
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.users = JSON.parse(userDataJson)
  },
....
}
```